# GPS example with Kivy and plyer doesn't work on Android

Tags: android, gps, kivy

I recently discovered Kivy and have been playing around with some of the simple examples. I modified some of the code in Dusty Phillips book Creating Apps in Kivy but couldn't get GPS output on my Android Phone. I simply want the code to display the location every second. Here is the relevant section of my main.py file:

```
class AddLocationForm(BoxLayout):
    def myclock(self, *args):
        try:


            gps.start()

        except:
            self.outputs.item_strings=["", "No Location", str(random.random())]

    @mainthread
    def on_location(self, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.outputs.item_strings = ["","","", str(kwargs['lat']),"","","",str(kwargs['lon']), "","","",str(random.random())]
        except:
            pass
    def on_status(sefl, **kwargs):
        self.outputs.item_strings = ["", "","", "On status", "", "",str(random.random())]

    def send_location(self):
        try:

            gps.configure(on_location=self.on_location, on_status=self.on_status)

            Clock.schedule_interval(self.myclock, 1)
        except NotImplementedError:
            self.outputs.item_strings=["", "No GPS", str(random.random())]



class WeatherApp(App):
    def on_pause(self):
        return True

if __name__=='__main__':
    WeatherApp().run()
```

and my KV file is:

```
AddLocationForm:

<AddLocationForm>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    outputs: outputs_list
    BoxLayout:
        height: "40dp" 
        size_hint_y: None
        Button:
            text: "Start"
            size_hint_x: 25 
            on_press: root.send_location()
        Button:
            text: "End"
            size_hint_x: 25 
    ListView: 
        id: outputs_list
        item_strings: []
```

The app works well on my desktop because it gets to the NotImplementedError. When I compile the app (with buildozer by running `buildozer android debug` to create the .apk file) and install it on my Android phone it seems to work at first for about a minute and then freezes with no response whatsoever. It doesn't seem to be an issue with the pausing/running in background at first. For example, I can switch between apps and come back to it and it still outputs the location. However, after some time the app just freezes ... without running `send_location()` more than once

I have enabled access and premissions and plyer library in the buildozer.specs file

Comment: Does logcat give any useful info? Also, did you add the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permissions?

Comment: Ryan, thanks for the suggestion. I use both Fine and Coarse location.  I actually made it work by modifying kwargs['lat'] into str(kwargs['lat']), however, now the app seems to become unresponsive after a minute or so (although it works at first) any suggestions?

Comment: Not enough info in your code above to answer that. Though if you call `send_location` more than once, that's possibly the issue.

Comment: Thanks again for your response. I have modified the code above to include everything including the KV file ....

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to make sure that you don't call `gps.configure()` or `gps.start()` more than once. I'd have to look at the plyer code to be certain about whether this is really an issue, but it's certainly a bad practice. Generally you should call those once when the app starts (`on_start` callback), then stop when your app pauses (`on_pause` callback), restart when your app resumes (`on_resume` callback) and stop again when your app exits (`on_stop` callback). I often just put these calls in `on_pause` and `on_resume`, then have `on_start` call `on_resume`, and `on_stop` call `on_pause`. `gps.configure()` probably only needs to be called once ever, since it will hook up the events, and the events will start and stop firing when the GPS function is started and stopped.

But the reason for the freeze is likely that your `on_status` callback does not have the `@mainthread` decorator like `on_location` does. The `on_status` callback will be called periodically with `GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS`.

Comment: In the future I would like to transmit the location of the user continuously to a web app. In that case I do need the app to obtain the location even if running in background. I guess that implies that I need to call gps.start() more than once right?

Comment: You would need to use an Android service if you want to check this continually. Also need wake lock to keep polling when the device would otherwise go to sleep. tshirtman made a nice tutorial on services: http://kivy.org/planet/2014/01/building-a-background-application-on-android-with-kivy/